# How do I prove if the following functor is exact?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory, exact-sequence

I have the following exercise:

> Prove if the functor that sends an abelian group to it's $n$-torsion subgroup for $n\geq 2$ is exact.

I know that I need to take $f\colon M\to N$ and $g\colon N\to L$ of $R$-Modules in $\textrm{Ab}$ which is exact i.e. $\operatorname{im}(f)=\ker(g)$ then I need to show that for the functor $F$ also $\operatorname{im}(F(f))=\ker(F(g))$ holds. Then the functor is exact.

But somehow I first don't see how this functor works so it sends an abelian group $A$ to the set $\{g\in A:g^n=e\}$ so all the elements of order $n$.

Could someone maybe explain this a bit to me?

THanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Let $f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ be the function $n\mapsto2n$. Then the short exact sequence
$$
0\to\mathbb Z\overset{f}\to\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/2\to0
$$
is sent by the "torsion part" functor to
$$
0\to0\to0\to\mathbb Z/2\to0,
$$
which is not exact at $\mathbb Z/2$.

Answer (score 1):

With Abelian groups one usually applies additive notation.

Yes, $F(A)=\{a\in A:\,n\cdot a=0\}$.
Then, $F$ sends a homomorphism $f:A\to B$ to its restriction to $F(A)$, i e.
$$F(f):=f|_{F(A)}:F(A)\to F(B)$$
as it's clear that $f(a)\in F(B)$ whenever $a\in F(A)$.

Then, if ${\rm im}(f)=\ker g$ for a $g:B\to C$, then on one hand we have $g\circ f=0$, and on the other hand, $g(b)=0\implies\exists a\in A:\,f(a)=b$.
Can you finish from here?

Comment: sorry I don't get it yet, so are we proving that it is exact or not?

Comment: and why is $g\circ f=0$?

Comment: @Wave As $\operatorname{im}(f)=\ker(g)$ we have, in particular, $\operatorname{im}(f)\subseteq\ker(g)$ which is nothing else then to say that for all $m\in M$ we have $(g\circ f)(m)=g(f(m))=0$, i.e. $g\circ f$ is the zero map $g\circ f=0$. The answers hints at the fact that abelian groups are $\mathbb Z$-module, hence group homomorphisms commute with multiplication by integers. More explicitely, $f(n\cdot a)=n\cdot f(a)=n\cdot b$. Now think about what this means for the $n$-torsion.